# Spark: in a task the shuffle writes have multiplied the input records and the executor exited with OOM

Tags: apache-spark

I am running a spark job on a parquet file with 40M records, performing a group by operation with distinct count on 50 columns.

> Select count(distinct(column_a)), count(distinct(column_b)).......
> from table_1 group_by column_status.

The job failed with msg

> ExecutorLostFailure (executor 2 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container from a bad node: container_1705651623593_0002_01_000003 on host: ip-10-0-49-158.ap-south-1.compute.internal. Exit status: 137. Diagnostics: [2024-01-19 11:49:09.874]Container killed on request. Exit code is 137

In spark UI I noticed this
[image]

Why the shuffle write is ~8x the input records, I understand distinct count is a costly operation, just trying to understand why the records got multiplied and why distinct count is a costly operation?